# Are there any commonly used "Couldn't organise an X in a Y" phrases that aren't vulgar?

Tags: phrases, offensive-language

Are there any phrases like "Couldn't organise a piss-up in a brewery" or "Couldn't organise a root in a brothel" that are reasonably common, indicate organisational incompetence, have a degree of irony (as opposed to "Couldn't run a chook raffle", or answers to the more general question [Is there a proverb or idiom describing incompetence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344125/is-there-a-proverb-or-idiom-describing-incompetence)) and aren't vulgar?

Wiktionary suggests [couldn't organise a bun fight in a bakery](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/couldn%27t_organise_a_bun_fight_in_a_bakery#English), and while it does appear in real life (example: [Brisbane port ready for naval expansion](http://www.smh.com.au/federal-politics/federal-election-2013/brisbane-port-ready-for-naval-expansion-20130827-2soa1.html)), it doesn't appear to be common. Are there any that are non-vulgar and are more common?

Related, but not as specific in its requirements: [Is there a proverb or idiom describing incompetence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344125/is-there-a-proverb-or-idiom-describing-incompetence)

Comment: In case anyone's wondering: it's prompted by a [real estate magnate reportedly not being able to book a hotel room](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world-0/us-politics/donald-trump-g20-summit-hamburg-hotel-room-germany-us-president-meetings-a7827166.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a proverb or idiom describing incompetence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344125/is-there-a-proverb-or-idiom-describing-incompetence)

Comment: I'm sure some of the answers in the possible duplicate are non-vulgar. Have a look. :)

Comment: @NVZ "Couldn't hit water if they fell out of a boat." has the required level of irony, but isn't about organisational incompetence. The rest aren't ironic, or are vulgar.

Comment: A mostly-vulgar list can be found here: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-406278.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Elephind search turns up a number of relatively mild yet colorful antecedents to the more vulgar "couldn't organize an X in a Y" expressions that Andrew Grimm mentions.

From "[The Banana Busisiness](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84024441/1899-04-15/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22couldn%27t%2Borganize%2Ba%22)," in the *[Washington, D.C.] Evening Times* (April 15, 1899), reprinted from the *New Orleans [Louisiana] Times-Democrat*:

> Why, the Chinese banana growers of Bocas **couldn't organize a flatboat**.

From an [untitled item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86081889/1905-06-21/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22couldn%27t%2Borganize%2Ba%22) in the *[McConnellsburg, Pennsylvania] Fulton County News* (June 21, 1905), reprinted over the ensuing month in newspapers in Virginia and Washington State:

> Men who **couldn't organize a peanut stand** know just how the pastor should run the church.

From Frank Crane, "[Recognize Mexico](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=TWN19220608.1.6&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22-------)," in the *[Roanoke, Virginia] World News* (June 8, 1922):

> About the time of de la Huerta's visit, a revolution was staged under the leadership of Felix Diaz. Diaz is a toothless has-been, and **couldn't organize a revolution in a chicken coop**.

From Lemuel Parton, "[Dollars Will Go Swiftly During Approaching Political Campaign Despite Huge Sums to Be Raised](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19280725&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522couldn%252527t+organize+a%252522-------1)," in the *San Bernardino [California] Sun* (July 25, 1928):

> Some of them are experienced political workers who know how to organize a district; others are out-moded and broken-down politicians who **couldn't organize a game of horseshoes** and still others are confidence men who are accustomed to selling political prestige which they do not possess.

Expressions that appear in newspapers from the 1970s and later include the following:

> **couldn’t organize a two-car funeral** [*Golden [Colorado] Transcript*](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/colorado?a=d&d=GOT19720407-01.2.32&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22-------0--) (April 7, 1972)

> **couldn't organize a box lunch** [*[Denver, Colorado] Paper*](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/colorado?a=d&d=PPR19720802-01.2.9&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22-------0--) (August 2, 1972)

> **couldn’t organize a procession to the bathroom** [*[Denver Colorado] Fourth Estate*](https://www.coloradohistoricnewspapers.org/cgi-bin/colorado?a=d&d=FTE19740410-01.2.10&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxCO%7ctxTA-%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22-------0--) (April 10, 1974)

> **couldn’t organize a one-car funeral** [*Santa Cruz [California] Sentinel*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCS19810507.1.50&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522couldn%252527t+organize+a%252522-------1) (May 7, 1981)

> **couldn't organize a rock to fall off a cliff** [*Canadian [Texas] Record*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth220540/m1/8/zoom/?q=%22couldn%27t%20organize%20a%22&resolution=4&lat=2550&lon=1650) (August 1, 2002)

> **couldn't organize a bake sale** [*Coronado [California] Eagle and Journal*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=CJ20081203.2.30&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522couldn%252527t+organize+a%252522-------1) (December 3, 2008)

Google Books search delivers a number of additional possibilities, going back to 1915:

> **couldn't organize a clambake** Trumbull Electric Manufacturing Co., [*Trumbull Cheer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=a5lAAQAAMAAJ&q=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&dq=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSqf7nxq3rAhXbJTQIHU_8DUsQ6AEwCHoECAcQAg) (1915)

> **couldn't organize a bunch of tom-cats around a bowl of milk** International Woodworkers of America, [*Proceedings of the Constitutional Convention*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zVdGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&dq=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg862_x63rAhVkCTQIHVL9AWcQ6AEwBHoECAUQAg) (1939)

> **couldn't organize a game of slapjack** Paul Bonner, [*Excelsior*](https://books.google.com/books?id=o7Q4fu12resC&q=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&dq=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEuNaLya3rAhW1ITQIHeyLAZ8Q6AEwBnoECAcQAg) (1955)

> **couldn't organize a crap game** William Brammer, [*The Gay Place*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UNc4q0tDBqoC&q=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&dq=%22couldn%27t+organize+a%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY_uvGya3rAhXlHDQIHewUAWMQ6AEwA3oECAEQAg) (1961)

I have encountered the "game of horseshoes," "bake sale," and "one-car [or two-car] funeral" variants of organizational haplessness over the years; but for fidelity to the form that Andrew Grimm is most interested in, "couldn't organize a revolution in a chicken coop" is pretty hard to beat.

Comment: Most of these examples do not follow the "an X **in a  Y**" formula that the OP asked for. Lots of good examples of organisational incompetence, but few actually relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary also suggests  ***[couldn't pour water out of a boot](http://couldn't%20pour%20water%20out%20of%20a%20boot)*** which does sound less vulgar that the others options.

Alternative form:

> couldn't pour water out of a boot with the instructions on the heel.
>
> (Synonym of couldn't organise a piss-up in a brewery)

Comment: This isn't quite the same, though: it doesn't describe _organizational_ incompetence in the way that the examples in the question do.  I did get a chuckle out of the alternative form, though.

Answer (score 1):

"He couldn't organize his way out of a wet paper bag."

> I am the organizer in my house, but I am also the breadwinner, so my husband does the schooling. **He couldn't organize his way out of a wet paper bag** without a manual. (I love him, but he is the archeotype of an artist)

http://www.time4learning.net/forum/kindergarten-through-third-grade/feeling-overwhelming-urge-homeschool-22052/#post62678

It's obviously a bit casual, but if you Google *"organize""out of a wet paper bag"*, you find countless examples buried in forums and video comments.

> Good afternoon, please could someone help me with this phrase? I cannot understand its meaning.
>
> Entrepreneurs are obsessed with freedom... and have an enormous work
>   ethic," she says.  But she concedes: "We couldn't organise ourselves
>   out of a paper bag!"

discussion here - https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/out-of-a-paper-bag.28317/

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly more pointed way is to say "As much use as".

e.g.

> John Smith was so dimwitted that he was said to be as much use as a
> chocolate teapot.

or

> "as an ashtray on a motorbike"

or

> "as teats on a bull"